# Corolla 2008 Replacement Key (program transponder chip)

Tags: corolla, key

Thanks for reading my post.

I have 2008 Corolla ascent zre152r HATCHBACK automatic having a master key with a single dot on it. Recently, I bought a blank single dot transponder key from eBay. Now, I'm trying to program the key with the steps mentioned at following, but no luck! :(

1. https://itstillruns.com/program-toyota-transponder-chip-key-5054034.html
2. http://bitsofmymind.com/2016/02/11/how-to-program-a-new-toyota-transponder-key/

I have this car in Western Australia.

Thanks.

Comment: No manual programming method for these. You must use a obd tool capable of programming for them.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's another](http://www.san-francisco-locksmith.us/program-toyota-transponder-chip-key/), slightly different, description. I imagine that there will be many different methods for different model years and computers.

My buddy says you need a Toyota computer (at least with the Prius models), so it may not be possible on your Corolla... it's not really easy to get a definitive answer via Google alone. You can do some more searching, but you may also want to check with some locksmiths and just ask them if they can do it. If they can, then you don't need a Toyota dealer computer. If they can't, then you probably have to go to the dealer.

The only guaranteed way I can say is via a dealer. It will be the more expensive option, but it will work 100%.

---

As a note, I'm in the US, so there may be different laws in Australia that govern how manufacturers have to set those things up. Honestly, I don't know, but it's possible.